# map is not a function in list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I make a request that returns a simple list, I'm trying to interact with this list in a table, but I'm having a following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: this.state.sistemas.map is not a function
>       at App.render (App.js:46)

My component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { sistemas: [] };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5acaad042e00004d00bbaa07')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({ sistemas: response.data });
        console.log('Response', response.data);
      }.bind(this))
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log('Indo buscar dados');
    axios.get('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5acaad042e00004d00bbaa07')
      .then(function (response) {
        this.setState({ sistemas: response.data });
      }.bind(this))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <button className='button' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Click Me
      </button>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.sistemas.map(sistema =>
              <li key={sistema.id}>{sistema.nome}</li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

@edit

I added a console.log in the resolution of the promise to show the result of the response.data

console.log in componentDidMount return:

```
Response:  [
{id: '1', nome: 'Sistema 01'},
{id: '2', nome: 'Sistema 02'},
{id: '3', nome: 'Sistema 03'},
{id: '4', nome: 'Sistema 04'},
{id: '5', nome: 'Sistema 05'},
{id: '6', nome: 'Sistema 06'},
{id: '7', nome: 'Sistema 07'},
{id: '8', nome: 'Sistema 08'},
{id: '9', nome: 'Sistema 09'},
{id: '10', nome: 'Sistema 10'},
{id: '11', nome: 'Sistema 11'},
```

]

Comment: are you certain `response.data` is an array, not a string or object?

Comment: console.log('Response: ', response.data) return Response:  [
    {id = '1', nome = 'Sistema 01'},
    {id = '2', nome = 'Sistema 02'},
    {id = '3', nome = 'Sistema 03'},
    {id = '4', nome = 'Sistema 04'},
    {id = '5', nome = 'Sistema 05'},
    {id = '6', nome = 'Sistema 06'},
    {id = '7', nome = 'Sistema 07'},
    {id = '8', nome = 'Sistema 08'},
    {id = '9', nome = 'Sistema 09'},
    {id = '10', nome = 'Sistema 10'},
    {id = '11', nome = 'Sistema 11'},
    
]

Comment: I see your update, the trailing `,` is not valid JSON.

I would suggest you look for an object->json converter in what ever code your API is written in, it looks like you are attempting to generate the JSON yourself which is not recommended. Do a google search for `[API language] json serialization`

Comment: I have corrected json, but I have the following problem: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, nome}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Then you need to resolve this question, as it was answered, and start another question *only if* you can't solve it yourself. Im sure you can google around and find out how to fix that react error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the syntax of your data array. I think the equals signs are messing up the data structure.

---

Your API, http://www.mocky.io/v2/5acaa5562e00004900bba9f7 returns invalid JSON

```
[
    {id = '1', nome = 'Sistema 01'},
    {id = '2', nome = 'Sistema 02'},
    {id = '3', nome = 'Sistema 03'},
    {id = '4', nome = 'Sistema 04'},
    {id = '5', nome = 'Sistema 05'},
    {id = '6', nome = 'Sistema 06'},
    {id = '7', nome = 'Sistema 07'},
    {id = '8', nome = 'Sistema 08'},
    {id = '9', nome = 'Sistema 09'},
    {id = '10', nome = 'Sistema 10'},
    {id = '11', nome = 'Sistema 11'},

]

Error: Parse error on line 2:
[    {id = '1', nome = 'Si
------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}'
```

Comment: @RafaelAugusto did you? what does the API return now?

Comment: The problem continues. I think it's something wrong with the way I do .map

Comment: For it to be valid json you need to put double quotes on all keys and strings and you will need to remove the trailing comma after the last object in the area.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto it is a problem with your JSON. The axios library will attempt to convert valid JSON into a javascript object and attach it as `response.data`. Look into properly serialising your data as JSON before looking at your front end code

Comment: I have corrected json, but I have the following problem: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, nome}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.